# Differentiability at (0,0).

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I always get stuck when I've to show something is differentiable,like in the following question:

$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{x^3y^3}{x^4+y^4} & \text{if $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$} \\ 0 & \text{if $(x,y)=(0,0)$} \end{cases}$

show that f is differentiable at (0,0) ...

First I thought of showing that partial derivatives exist for the
point (0, 0).

### $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{0}{x^4}}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{{0}}{x^5}= 0$$

later in relation to y:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(0,y)-f(0,0)}{y -0}=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{0}{y^4}}{y}=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{{0}}{y^5}= 0$$

alright both partial derivatives exists and are equal,so now we have to show that :they are continuous near (0,0)..

but that doesn't prove the limit is differentiable, what can I do?

I thought of using the following formula for a corollary.

$$E(h,k)=f(x_0 +h, y_0 +k)-f(x_0, y_0)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)h -\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)k$$

however:

$$E(h,k)=\frac{(x_0+h)^3(y_0+k)^3} {(x_0 + h)^4 + (y_0 +k)^4}  -\frac{x^3 y^3}{x^4 + y^4}-0h -0k$$

Comment: What definition do you have for differentiability?

Comment: Check your work.  $f(x,0)$ is not equal to $x^3/x^4$.

Comment: but in the function $f(x,y)$ is $\frac {x^3 y^3}{x^4+y^4}$

Comment: Is $x\neq 0$ then $f(x,0)=\frac{x^3\cdot 0^3}{x^4+0^4}=0$. What is the definition of differentiability that you're using?

Comment: First I thought of showing that partial derivatives exist for the
point (0, 0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have correctly computed that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$.

A function is said to be differentiable at a point $(a,b)$ iff there exist $\phi(h,k)$ and $\psi(h,k)$ from $\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that

$f(a+h,b+k)=h\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\vert_{(a,b)}+k\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\vert_{(a,b)}+h\phi(h,k)+k\psi(h,k)$ such that  $\phi(h,k)\to 0\quad \text{and}\quad\psi(h,k)\to 0$ as $(h,k)\to(0,0)$.

So if our given function is differentiable.

Then $f(0+h,0+k)=h\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+k\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+h\phi(h,k) +k\psi(h,k)$ where $\psi$ and $\phi$ both $\to 0$ as $(h,k)\to (0,0)$ .

Then $\dfrac{h^3k^3}{h^4+k^4}=h\phi(h,k)+k\psi(h,k)$.

Take $\displaystyle\phi(h,k)=\frac{h^{2}k^{3}}{2(h^{4}+k^{4})}$
and $\displaystyle\psi(h,k)=\frac{k^{2}h^{3}}{2(h^{4}+k^{4})}$.

Then both $\phi$ and $\psi$ tend to $0$ as $(h,k)\to(0,0)$.

Hence you have differentiability.

In a Equivalent formulation of Differentiability.

A function is differentiable at a point $(a,b)$ iff there exist $\psi(h,k)$

$f(a+h,b+k)=h\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\vert_{(a,b)}+k\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\vert_{(a,b)}+\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}}\cdot \psi(h,k)$ such that $\psi(h,k)\to 0$ as $(h,k)\to(0,0)$.

In this case you just take $\displaystyle\psi=\frac{h^3k^3}{(h^4+k^4)\sqrt{(h^{2}+k^{2})}}$ . Then this would also imply differentiablity.

It's just a matter of what convention you follow. Many people like this norm formulation. I myself prefer the previous one. They are both equivalent.

Lastly, I would say that you should try and use polar coordinates to show that $\psi$ and $\phi$ tend to $0$. It is very easy. $\cos^{4}(\theta)+\sin^{4}(\theta)\geq \frac{1}{2}$ always.

Comment: Could you tell me why in the corollary you added it all up and what does the:
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}h |_(a,b)$
and what does it mean ϕ  and ψ?

Comment: @Skye $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}|_{(a,b)}$ just means evaluated at $(a,b)$. Nothing else. And $\phi$ and $\psi$ are two functions from $\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that both tend to $0$ as $(h,k)\to(0,0)$

Comment: Got it, can you show me where I can study a formula you presented at the beginning?

Comment: It's just a formulation of differentiation. Many people also wirte it as $\frac{f(a+h,b+k)-hf_{x}-kf_{y}}{\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}}}\to 0 $ as $(h,k)\to (0,0)$. Here $f_{x}$ means partial derivative. I wouls suggest you the book by Satish Shirali and Harikrishna Lal Vasudeva on multivariable calculus for this reference. It is frankly imo the best book on the topic and it helped me a lot at the undergrad level.

Comment: Also @Skye you can mark as answer if it has answered your question

Comment: can you explain the part that originated "Take $ ϕ(h,k)=\frac{h^2 k^3} {2(h^4 +k^4)}$?where did the 2 come from?

Comment: @Skye If you look at what I wrote....you will see that I said "differentiable iff there exist functions $\phi$ and $\psi$. So we are doing exactly that. We are constructing functions $\phi$ and $\psi$ which satisfy the given constraints. Since we are able to construct such function , it is differentiable. And to answer your query , the $2$ is kept so that RHS = LHS. so that when you add $h\phi + k\psi$ you end up with the LHS. Otherwise you will get a useless $2$ in the numerator.

Comment: Hi Mr. Gandalf, I again... was wondering why we just can't say by showing that the partial derivatives of f are
in continuous (0, 0).
Doesn't that prove that f is differentiable at (0,0)?

Comment: The continuity of partial derivatives provide a sufficient condition for differentiability. If you want to use that it is fine....but why bother if we can show it directly? .

Comment: It would be like using a theorem to show something which directly follows from definition.